# ID from command argument error when filter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make a link detail from database, I use linkbutton on templatefield gridview to go to the database details according to each id, I use like code below method works properly but when I filter the result and click certain row, the Id received in the server end seems to be different not corresponding to what I clicked. I feel it gets the wrong row index... this happens only when I try filtering and perform row command click. Other wise it works properly. Why is this.

```xml
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nama File" ItemStyle-Width="300px">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID ="InkView1" runat ="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' OnCommand="linkDownloadFile1_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

code behind

```cs
int ImageId = Convert.ToInt32((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
```